# Fill an array with last non-zero element to the end in PHP

Tags: php, array

I need to fill an array with the last non-zero value.

Points of note I guess are that the array will either have all `0` values or end with `0` values.

Please review my code below.

```
<?php

$array = [1, 1, 5, 4, 0, 0];
$array2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];


function padArray($array) {
    $length = count($array) - 1;
    for ($i = $length; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        if($array[$i] != 0) {
            for ($j = $i; $j < count($array); $j++) {
                $array[$j] = $array[$i];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}


var_dump(padArray($array));
var_dump(padArray($array2));

//should output [1,1,5,4,4,4]
//should output [0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do you really want this function to use loose comparison `$array[$i] != 0`?  What should intended behavior be for other potentially falsey values at the end of the array (`false`, `""`, `[]`, etc.)?  If you truly only want to replace only trailing zeroes, then you **must** use exact comparison here `!==`.
- Your function name seems unclear with regards to what the function does.  Perhaps `arrayPadOverTrailingZeroes`, `arrayPadOverTrailingEmptyValues` (depending on desired behavior).
- PHP provides built-in array functions that may clean up this code a little bit (and perhaps perform slightly better since they are compiled).

For example:

```
function arrayPadOverTrailingZeroes($array) {
    $length = count($array);
    while (($value = end($array)) === 0) {
        array_pop($array);
    }
    // This conditional to support case where you have all zeroes,
    // in which case, the while loop above would have discarded all array members
    // and $value would be set to false
    if (count($array) === 0) {
        $value = 0;
    }
    return array_pad($array, $length, $value);
}
```

Answered this before I saw your all-zeroes use case.  Added some additional logic above to handle this case.

Comment: Great catch on the loose comparison. Will move to built in functions and yes a more descriptive name would make sense.

Comment: About performances: https://eval.in/764866

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>             for ($j = $i; $j < count($array); $j++) {
>                 $array[$j] = $array[$i];
>             }
> ```

PHP has built-in functions for this:

```
            array_pad(array_slice($array, 0, $i + 1), $length + 1, $array[i]);
```

or

```
            $firstZero = $i + 1;
            $zeroCount = count($array) - $i;
            $suffix = array_fill($firstZero, $zeroCount, $array[$i]);
            $array = array_splice($array, $firstZero, $zeroCount, $suffix);
```

This also doesn't copy `$array[$i]` over `$array[$i]` which may be harmless in terms of effect but is a waste.

Consider renaming `$length` to something like `$last`, as it isn't the length but the zero-indexed location of the last value.

We can actually simplify the whole function to

```
    $firstZero = array_search(0, $array, true);
    $lastNonZero = $firstZero - 1;
    if ($firstZero > 0) {
        array_pad(array_slice($array, 0, $firstZero), count($array), $lastNonZero);
    }

    return $array;
```

I find this more readable as to what it is doing.  We're finding the first index of a zero element and thus the last index of a non-zero element.  If the first element isn't already zero, we fill all the elements starting with the zero element with the last non-zero value.

The described inputs always include a zero in the array.  But if someone passes an array without a zero, `false` is not greater than zero, so it just returns the original array.  If you prefer, you could write this explicitly as

```
    if ($firstZero !== false && $firstZero > 0) {
```

or

```
    if ($firstZero === false) {
        return $array;
    }
```

But the behavior will be correct without that.

It also may be faster, as the built-in functions are often faster than the manual versions.

Comment: Probably best to search from back of array so you iterate over fewer values.  Also you have edge case not addressed here for when `array_search()` returns `false` (i.e. there are no non-zero items in array)

Comment: Actually your function doesn't work at all since the return of `array_fill` is blowing in the wind. You can't also use `array_search` with this kind of array `[1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your actual project arrays will be a relatively small size (like your posted input arrays), there is going to be an unnoticeable margin of speed between the many ways that this can be done.

Here is a method that doesn't use a loop or `array_search()`.  The else portion of my `replaceTrailingZeros()` function could have been condensed into a one-liner, but I've declared `$replace` to make it easier to read.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5550ac6335f2c5827e2aee2e381f53c3b415ac84))

```
function replaceTrailingZeros($array) {
    $trimmed = array_diff($array, [0]);  // remove all zeros
    // seek last non-zero value (store value or false) and move array pointer to last element
    if (($last = end($trimmed)) === false) {
        return $array;  // nothing to change
    } else {
        // generate minimal array from zero element keys and last non-zero value
        $replace = array_fill($index = key($trimmed) + 1, sizeof($array) - $index, $last);
        return array_replace($array, $replace);  // only replace the trailing zero elements
    }
}
echo implode(',', replaceTrailingZeros([1,0,1,0,5,4,0,0,0,0])); // 1,0,1,0,5,4,4,4,4,4 (5 native func calls)
echo "\n";
echo implode(',', replaceTrailingZeros([0,0,0])); // 0,0,0 (just 2 native func calls)
echo "\n";
echo implode(',', replaceTrailingZeros([1,1,5,4,0,0])); // 1,1,5,4,4,4 (5 native func calls)
```

---

**Older and wiser**... using minimal function calls and relying on language constructs are great ways to maximize script efficiency.  You actually could have gotten away with using `$length` in both of your loops.

```
$length = count($array);
for ($i = $length - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
    if ($array[$i] !== 0) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $length; ++$j) {
            $array[$j] = $array[$i];
        }
        break;
    }
}
return $array;
```

If you wanted to remove the nested loop, you could use `array_replace()` and `array_fill()`, but they won't outperform a simple `for()` loop.

```
$length = sizeof($array);
for ($i = $length - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
    if ($array[$i] !== 0) {
        return array_replace($array, array_fill($i, $length - $i, $array[$i]));
    }
}
return $array;
```